# Custom Cells in TableView

Tags: scala, javafx, scalafx

I'm working on a scalafx project and I'd like a TableView where some of the Cells contain a button. I've found an example of how to put a graphic inside of a [tablecell](http://www.scalafx.org/docs/faq_TableView_with_Custom_cell/). When I use example and only replace the call to `graphic = ...` to use a button I will sometimes get Cells where every column is empty except the one whith the button:

[image: screenshot]

How do i fix this? (I've checked that it's not just an empty string on the name value, so that last login button should not be there)

Here is the code from the example modified to use a button:

```
new TableColumn[Person, String] {
        text = "Login"
        cellValueFactory = { _.value.favoriteColor }
        cellFactory = { _ =>
          new TableCell[Person, String] {
            item.onChange { (_, _, newColor) =>
              graphic = new Button {
                text = "Login"
                onAction = {
                  (e: ActionEvent) => println("pressed the button")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Caveat: I'm not a Scala programmer, so I can only answer this from a JavaFX perspective. You should be able to translate this to Scala though.)

You need to check whether the `TableCell` is empty, and set the graphic to `null` if the cell is empty, and to the button otherwise.

Additionally, it's not a good idea to create a new button every time the `item` changes (which can be quite frequently); you should instead create it once when a new cell is created (which is rare) and then just set it (or `null`) as the graphic when the `item` changes.

In Java 8 the code looks like this:

```
TableColumn<Person, String> column = new TableColumn<>("Login");
column.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().favoriteColorProperty());

column.setCellFactory( col -> {

    TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<>();

    Button button = new Button("Login");
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.out.println("pressed the button");
        // you can call cell.getItem() if you want to do something specific for this cell
    });

    cell.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

    cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        if (newItem == null) {
            cell.setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            cell.setGraphic(button);
        }
    });

    return cell ;
});
```

Here I am assuming the item is only ever `null` for empty cells: if this is not the case you need to either subclass `TableCell` and override the `updateItem(...)` method, or observe both the `itemProperty()` and the `emptyProperty()` of a default `TableCell`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works perfectly. Look at my answer to see your code translated to scala

Answer (score 0):

Heres James_D's answer in scala:

```
new TableColumn[Person, String] {
  text = "Login" 
  cellValueFactory = { _.value.name } //it actually doesn't matter which value you choose here
  cellFactory = { _ =>
    val cell = new TableCell[Person, String]()
    val btn = new Button {
      text = "Login"
      onAction = { (e: ActionEvent) =>
        println("Button pressed")
      }
    }
    cell.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY)

    cell.itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener[String] {
      override def changed(obs: ObservableValue[_ <: String], oldItem: String, newItem: String): Unit = {
        if (newItem == null) {
          cell.setGraphic(null)
        } else {
          cell.setGraphic(btn)
        }
      }
    })

    cell
  }
}
```